# How can I get updated column names from different tables and insert their data with column name in a single history table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a history table like below

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[t_PettyCash_History] 
(
    [TableName] [varchar] (500) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [ColumnName] [varchar] (500) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [PreviousValue] [varchar] (500) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [CurrentValue] [varchar] (500) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [UpdatedBy] [varchar] (500) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [UpdateDate] [varchar] (500) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL 
)
```

What I am trying to do is to write a trigger or stored_procedure which will do the below

1. Select the name of the table which is updated
2. Select the name of the column in which data is inserted, updated or deleted
3. then insert the values in above table similar like

   ```
   TableName  ColumnName  PreviousValue   CurrentValue  UpdatedBy   UpdateDate
   t_Table1        Col1        XXX             YYY        A       '20-Mar-2012'
   ```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I tried to create individual History tables for all my tables which works fine to store the history information. but for me it is NOT a good solution because thats just double up my table quantities. I use triggers and "inserted" and "deleted" virtual tables for this. But i want to keep all the history information in a single history table.

Comment: If you have much activity in your DB than the single history table will become a bottleneck.  Presumable each transdaction will have to access it for each Insert, update and delete - system wide.  Multiple history tables is IMHO b etter for this single reason alone.  What problem do you see with having double the number of tables?  In my experience table numbers are not really a problem till you get up to 10 000 or more.  Asuuming a good naming standard to help keep track of them.

Comment: I have a question. If you do a bulk update, how is your current trigger handling that? If you are going to have a global trigger to do the work, then you must have some way of linking `inserted` with `deleted` that will make it unique, otherwise you will have all kinds of problems

Comment: Currently I am serving the purpose with individual triggers for each table like Karl suggested. And yes, @Jaques, I agreed with you. I thought a single trigger might serve but seems that I am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being agreed with **Karl**, currently using individual history table to keep track the changes of each tables. That is, created history table for each table and wrote triggers on main tables for insert, update, and delete action.